# Speed up encoding ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I have this for loop to reduce the size of videos files. I'm very new to ffmpeg and video encoding.
`for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -c:v libx265 -preset medium -crf 39 -c:a aac -b:a 128k -y new-"$i"; done`

My goal is to reduce the file size of some video files.(.mp4)

But it takes forever to complete, I'm looking for tips to make this faster.

Here is the output for reference:

```
> x265 [info]: frame threads / pool features       : 3 / wpp(17 rows)
> x265 [info]: Coding QT: max CU size, min CU size : 64 / 8 x265 [info]:
> Residual QT: max TU size, max depth : 32 / 1 inter / 1 intra x265
> [info]: ME / range / subpel / merge         : hex / 57 / 2 / 3 x265
> [info]: Keyframe min / max / scenecut / bias: 25 / 250 / 40 / 5.00
> x265 [info]: Lookahead / bframes / badapt        : 20 / 4 / 2 x265
> [info]: b-pyramid / weightp / weightb       : 1 / 1 / 0 x265 [info]:
> References / ref-limit  cu / depth  : 3 / off / on x265 [info]: AQ:
> mode / str / qg-size / cu-tree  : 2 / 1.0 / 32 / 1 x265 [info]: Rate
> Control / qCompress            : CRF-39.0 / 0.60 x265 [info]: tools:
> rd=3 psy-rd=2.00 early-skip rskip signhide tmvp b-intra x265 [info]:
> tools: strong-intra-smoothing lslices=6 deblock sao Output #0, mp4, to
> 'file.mp4':   Metadata:
>     major_brand     : isom
>     minor_version   : 512
>     compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
>     encoder         : Lavf58.29.100
>     Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (libx265) (hev1 / 0x31766568), yuv420p, 1920x1080 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], q=2-31, 60 fps, 15360 tbn, 60
> tbc (default)
>     Metadata:
>       handler_name    : VideoHandler
>       encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 libx265
>     Side data:
>       cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/0 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: -1
>     Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s (default)
>     Metadata:
>       handler_name    : SoundHandler
>       encoder         : Lavc58.54.100 aac frame=191017 fps= 33 q=-0.0 size=  163584kB time=00:53:03.71 bitrate= 420.9kbits/s dup=516 drop=0
> speed=0.542x
```

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! Is your goal to learn the ffmpeg command line tool, or to compress your videos without much visual loss?

Comment: Make the file size of my big video files smaller without significant quality loss. A little bit is ok (compress videos) @DarkDiamond. I already the ffmpeg manpages but it's dazzling me with so many options.

Comment: Well, then you should take a look into the tool [other-video-transcoding](https://github.com/donmelton/other_video_transcoding/). It is made for exactly that problem, especially for compressing ripped BluRay discs. I use it a lot to compress the videos of some of the lectures at my university, it works great. If you want me to explain some more I will write an answer.

Comment: It fails with the following: `Unrecognized option 'default_mode'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found`

Comment: What fails with the mentioned error? ffmpeg or other-video-transcoding?

Comment: Other-transcoding (but the log of other-transcoding says it's a ffmpeg error)

Comment: It seems like other-transcoding is calling this : `ffmpeg -loglevel error -stats -i "file.mp4" -map 0:0 -c:v libx264 -b:v 6000k -maxrate:v 20000k -bufsize:v 20000k -mbtree:v 0 -profile:v high -color_primaries:v bt709 -color_trc:v bt709 -colorspace:v bt709 -metadata:s:v "title=" -disposition:v default -map 0:1 -c:a:0 copy -metadata:s:a:0 "title=" -disposition:a:0 default -sn -metadata:g "title=" -default_mode passthrough "file.mkv1` where -default-mode is not recognized

Comment: This looks like either you misspelled the file name, i.e. it should say ``file1.mkv`` instead of ``file.mkv1`` or there is a problem with the quotation marks. I just used the tool yesterday and tried a dummy conversion just now and in the log it says ``-sn -metadata:g title= -default_mode passthrough C0001.mkv`` which looks similar to your case.

Comment: Yeah file1.mkv1 was a typo, sorry